# How can I increment counter when the value in another column changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I have the following table

```
ID      
12     
12    
25    
25    
78    
78    
78
```

And I need to be able to increment the counter value when the `ID` changes.

```
ID    **COUNTER**  
12     1
12     1
25     2
25     2
78     3
78     3
78     3
```

How can this be done? Is it even possible?

Comment: @Hugo In the future when you post a question, you should post more details including what you have tried to get the result.

Comment: @Hugo And post the right question that you want to get answered. *Is this possible?* is not the right question (hint: *How can I do this?* is a better one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`dense_rank()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx):

```
select id,
  dense_rank() over(order by id)  Counter
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02442/2)

Result:

```
| ID | COUNTER |
----------------
| 12 |       1 |
| 12 |       1 |
| 25 |       2 |
| 25 |       2 |
| 78 |       3 |
| 78 |       3 |
| 78 |       3 |
```